# Component initialization order in polymer 2

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

We are migrating a medium sized app from polymer 1 to polymer 3. Thus far we are stuck in the intermediate step of getting our hybrid components to work.

We are encounting some difficulties regarding component initialization timing. For example:

```
<my-app>
  <my-component slot='componentslot'><my-component>
</my-app>
```

It seems there are cases where `my-component` is initialized before `my-app` is initialized. It might vary wether `my-component` is part of shadow- or light-dom.

We have a lot of tightly coupled components which depend on deterministic initialization order. For example there is a tree-like structure where every edge and every leaf uses events to discover it's own depth in the tree. Therefore we need top-level elements to be initialized before inner components.

But what we found so far was essentially: There is no garantuee for any initialization order of the components.

Is there an established pattern for solving this problem? Will this problem be solved in polymer 3 (so we don't need to care about it anyway)?

**Edit**

I was asked for some more specific examples

*Example 1*

```html
<my-layout>
  <my-complex-component id="1">
    <my-reuseable-part/>
  </my-complex-component>
  <my-complex-component id="2">
    <my-reuseable-part/>
  </my-complex-component>
  <some-other-component>
    <my-reuseable-part/>
  </some-other-component>
</my-layout>
```

I have some reuseable components which need to know if they are inside `my-complex-component` or`some-other-component`. `my-complex-component` uses a `context-discovery-behavior` which fires an event containing a callback as payload. `my-complex-component` and `some-other-component` have `context-behavior`s which listen to that event and answer it by invoking the callback.

But as `my-reusable-part` might be attached before `my-complex-component` or `some-other-component` is attached, this pattern does not work.

Registration of event listeners as well as firing the disovering event is done in `attached` (i.e. `connectedCallback`).

*Example 2*

```html
<my-tree>
  <my-tree-edge>
    <my-tree-edge>
      <my-leaf/>
      <my-tree-edge>
        <my-leaf/>
      </my-tree-edge>
    </my-tree-edge>
    <my-tree-edge>
      <my-leaf/>
    </my-tree-edge>
    <my-leaf/>
  </my-tree-edge>
</my-tree>
```

In the example above every leaf and edge needs to know how deep it is nested. Again every elements fires an event and its parent will answer the event. Again listener registration and event-firing is done in `attached`/`connectedCallback`. Again the mechanik fails if an inner node is attached before it's parents are attached.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you using the onReady  method  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dom-if` element if you stricly want to be sure first render `my-app` then you can let render `my-component` something like:

```
<my-app ready="{{myAppReady}}>
  <template is='dom-if' if="[[myAppReady]]">
    <my-component slot='componentslot'><my-component>
  </template>
</my-app>
```

at my-app script:

```
static get properties(){return {
      ready:{type:Boolean,
             notify:true,
             value:false 
}}
```

at this part, you may add  `computed:"checkThisValuesToBeSUre(x,[y]..)` in order to be sure if depended to some values or you may add various conditions in order to render `my-component`

Also, you may import `my-component.js` dynamically like:

At `my-app` 's parent script:

```
static get observers(){return ['_checkMyAppReady(myAppReady)']}

_checkMyAppReady(r){
   if(r) import('./my-component.js');
}
```

**EDIT**

If there are many elements occurs the same problem, then better to use `lazy-import.js`:

```
_checkMyAppReady(r){
   if(r) import('./lazy-import.js');
}
```

lazy-import.js

```
import './my-component.js';
import './my-component2.js';
import './my-component3.js';
...
```

Comment: Wrapping almost every element in a `dom-if` does seem like an awkward workaround.

Comment: @samjaf Actually After thinking a little bit, instead of wrapping every element.  dynamical import. I mean, you can import all second level ( here `my-component.js` ) under lazy-import.js file. If you want a specific example I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update. A solution using lazy imports would be nicer indeed. Sadly, this won't work in a situation where components of the same type are nested.

Comment: @samjaf What is the exact problem, so there may another solution instead of module loading sequential. I mean If you do not want to activate one script unless some data will comes from other elements then there are some solutions for this. So, please try to add more spesific problem that you have.